# soap extension and x64/i386

Tags: php, soap

I have a small problem with soap client.
We have 2 Linux servers: Debian x64 and Debian i686.

At Debian x64 php array transform to soap type: ArrayOfLong.
BUT! At Debian i686 php array transform to soap type: StringArray!

How I can use ArrayOfLong at Debian i686?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The size of an integer in PHP is machine-dependent. It can be 32-bit long or 64-bit long.

My guess is that your array contains numbers bigger than `2^31-1` (or smaller than `-2^31`). The 64-bit version can represent these numbers with a PHP integer, and so uses `ArrayOfLong`, but the the 32-bit can't, so they are being represented as strings instead.